# Pycharm: Not Finding Pika Library (in path)

Tags: import, pycharm, pythonpath, pika

I spent 4 hours, on something simple, trying to figure out why pycharm did not find my pika library when running from inside development environment.  The answer became obvious once found but for all you who are suffering from this simple issue try this:

Pycharm -> Run -> Configurations

Uncheck

Add content roots to PYTHONPATH

Add source roots to PYTHONPATH

[Run/Debug Configurations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrMXL.png)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

These settings should not result in you not finding the library in your PATH.

It's possible you have files in your project which mirror the names of the library or are otherwise interfering with resolution of the import name. You really should try to fix this issue right here, or you may find yourself having to debug even stranger problems after you send the code along to someone else.

Let's say that you're trying to run :

```
>>> import foo
```

This will look for foo.py, or a folder named foo containing `__init.py__` in your PYTHONPATH.

If your own code also contains foo.py (or a folder named foo containing `__init.py__`), python will import your own module instead of the site package you're actually trying to import.

This may seemingly work without error, but if you were instead to do :

```
>>> from foo import fooclass
```

This class does not exists in your library, and therefore you're going to get an ImportError.

Similarly, if you did :

```
>>> import foo
>>> c = foo.fooclass()
```

You should get an AttributeError

Adding your source roots to PYTHONPATH is a fairly common requirement, and something you may need if your project grows beyond a few files. Not being able to do that can result in some really laborious workarounds in the future.